# ensure_root in ink!

Tags: ink, sudo

For the runtime development the FRAME pallet system provide a [function ensure_root](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L950) that allow us to ensure that the origin `o` represents the root:

```
// Only root can call this extrinsic.
ensure_root(origin)?;
```

For example to ensure that who is calling the extrinsic is someone with SUDO privileges in the Rococo network or an extrinsic executed via governance on Polkadot.

Is there a way to do that with ink!?

A workaround is to deploy the smart contract with this root privileges and store the account as the owner of the contract.

Comment: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13644

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible because a contract assumes to be always called by a another address. In order for that to work we would need to add this functionality to `pallet-contracts`. We would need a host function like `is_root` which would be true if the `call` dispatchable was called by root. However, what would we return from `caller`? Probably a hard coded placeholder address.

There are also much more origins than root. Since runtime authors can just add more origins it is not possible to support all of them. Maybe supporting the ones used in the new government would be nice.

Comment: Interesting, I think would be a nice feature because it can be useful for some use cases. But I understand now why is not possible to support all options.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: A [PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13708) has been merged to **master** that allows Root to call contracts and adds the `caller_is_root() -> bool` method.
You can then use this to build your custom `ensure_root`.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks for the update